Tax deductables
I am looking to start a company which i will be the sole owner and employee of. This company i will use to reduce the cost of purchasing items that i personally want, but i will be purchasing it thorugh the company to take advantages of tax deductions (UK), the company will own and run a youtube account which i will post videos of me opening these products, (eg: a new phone unboxing etc) so that it is actually valid and it isnt a random company that doesnt do anything.
Is this legal and possible?

"This company i will use to reduce the cost of purchasing items that i personally want" -- Sorry , doesn't usually work that way.

I’m voting to close this question because "is it legal" is a question for an attorney.

This sounds like your intent is tax evasion. Now consider that HMRC has been playing this game for many years and you are a newbie at it, your chances are bet. And you at violating rool #1 for tax payers anywhere: Never make the tax office think that you think you more clever than they are.

Not sure about the UK, but in the US this would accomplish nothing: given that the shell company would start out with no money, you’d have to fund it with your own (already income-taxed) money. You don’t get to deduct business cash infusions against your own income tax. If the company started receiving revenue (eg from YouTube ads) it could then deduct expenses against that, but that doesn’t really help your other income.

For a US perspective: In the US, sales tax is collected at time and point of sale (similar to a VAT) and the only way to avoid them is for your company to be registered as a tax-exempt corporation. It's possible to avoid paying sales taxes on some online purchases but purchasing as a company vs. an individual doesn't change that.

No, this is not legal or possible. You can't get any significant personal benefit from goods bought by a business without paying tax+NI on that benefit, which would defeat the purpose of your plan.
